# Showing SharePoint ribbon tabs to anonymous users

Tags: ribbon

I've asked this on other forums and gotten nowhere so I'm hoping you can help. I've created some custom ribbon tabs with buttons for site navigation. My issue is that although the ribbon buttons work correctly, the tabs only show to users that are logged in.

I think the issue is that SharePoint doesn't display ANY ribbon tabs (e.g. Browse) to unauthenticated users. Can someone help or at least tell me it's a lost cause that isn't possible.

Regards,
Kit

Comment: Is this a publishing site?

Comment: Yes. It is a publishing site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an OOB or a custom master page? With the OOB master page, there is no logic in place to hide the ribbon. But if you are using a custom master page, you might have logic in place which hides the ribbon via CSS for anonymous users. Look out for any CSS styling as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
     body #s4-ribbonrow{display: none;}
</style>
```

Either within a Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl control or a asp.net logged view control.

Comment: I have a custom master page but it's also happening with the OOB v4.master. There is no call to SPSecurityTrimmedControl and no CSS hiding it. To be clear ... it is tabs on the ribbon that don't show to anonymous users NOT the whole ribbon. I presume its because anonymous users don't get a choice of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the ViewFormsPagesLockDown feature. However, if this is a true public facing site, you may not want to disable that feature.

Comment: Hi Lori. I cant see that feature. Where is it located?

Comment: Found. Changed. No effect.